# No such file or directory while running docker

Tags: python, docker

I have a python file `server.py` that simply reads `LOGS_PATH` environment variable and sets uses it to create the target's logs directory.

```
logs_path = os.getenv("LOGS_PATH", "/logs/proxy.log")
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(logs_path)
```

My docker file has the following, notice that I create the logs directory and the `proxy.log` file.

```
EXPOSE 8000
CMD mkdir /logs
CMD touch /logs/proxy.log

CMD python server.py
```

Then I build the docker image and run it, as follows.

```
docker build -t rank
docker run --rm -it --net=host -p 8000:8000 --env-file=.env-co --name=rank rank
```

But when I run it, it blows up. It says `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/logs/proxy.log'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMD` and `RUN` are different things. Use as this:

```
EXPOSE 8000
RUN mkdir /logs
RUN touch /logs/proxy.log

CMD python server.py
```

CMD is the command that represents the container when running, an image can have only one CMD (the last one is the only valid). RUN is excuted when you do `docker build`.